# filename.delete() gives false in JAVA

Tags: java, io

I am generating report and trying to send it to user through email. This process works fine for 1 user. But when I am trying to send report to more than 1 user, I need to re-generate report and for that I need to delete previous report which is stored on server. So I am using following code.

```
if(newFileName.exists()){
   System.out.println("file delete:  "+newFileName.delete());
}
```

But it gives me false. Hence 2nd user receives same report as first user got. I have searched lots of solutions; but all are failed. Please can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you try to get the absolutePath first of the File (getAbsolutePath())? And do you close() the open FileInputStream?

Comment: You don't need to use this API ata ll. Just create a new `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter` or `PrintWriter`. If it can't be opened it will tell you, and with an informative exception, not just a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you cannot delete your file because the file is still in use in your process... Check if you don't have any Stream still opened with this file.

Or maybe you don't have enough permission for deleting file(s) on the server. Check this as well.

Try to use `Path` object and use this to have more information about why you have a problem : (Java 7 and up)

```
try {
    Files.delete(newFileName.toPath());
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Code from here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html

Maybe the best solution is to generate files with different names each other ?

Comment: Actually I have to send file with same name but with different content. Let me check if there is any stream is opened or not.

Comment: It's worked! Thanks Guillaume. I have used **InputStream** to upload file on server; but i forgot to close it.

Comment: I have voted you. but it says once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score. :)

Comment: @RajKhot Yeah, you can accept the answer if you think it's the good one ;)